# what is the simplest way to check if a .pdf file is a valid pdf document using itext?

Tags: itext

what is the simplest way to check if a .pdf file is a valid pdf document using itext?
I have written some code to open a .pdf using the itextsharp.dll, and if i try to open a bad .pdf (one that I have edited in notepad++ to corrupt it) then i get a PDFInvalid exception - which is all good (as opposed to no exception if the pdf is valid). 
However, I was wondering if there is another way to check for issues with pdf files.

I am about to extract a very large number of pdf documents from a database, and ideally would like to check that they are all valid pdf files - ie at least that they can be open.

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: That question is too broad, because you aren't telling us against what you want to validate. Do you want to validate against ISO-32000-1? That may be too strict, because plenty of PDFs that are in violation with the spec open perfectly in Adobe Reader. On the other hand: plenty of PDFs that are valid according to ISO-32000-1, don't open correctly in pdf.js (the PDF viewer in Firefox). What if a file pretends to be compliant with PDF/A. Do you want to validate that against ISO-19005? Currently nobody can do that correctly (but VeraPDF is doing the PREFORMA project with this goal).

Comment: Is there a way to read the filehash from the pdf file ? If so what version of the hash (Md5 or other) does pdf use ?. Think I need to a) check that the pdf is openable , and b) check the hash value with I) what windows thinks, ii) what the document management system thinks. That's all I can think of doing - but any other ideas would be very welcome. Kind regards.

Comment: By filehash you mean the digest of a signature?